# SSRS Add Months in current date with last day of month

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

I want to add months with last day in current date by using

**=dateadd(dateinterval.month, +4, DateAdd("d",-(Day(today)), Today))**

expression.

output is

current_date = 12/02/2014

finish_date  = 03/30/2014

The problem is that finsih_date month is 03(March) and last day of March is 31 but my parameter showing 30.

Comment: No ssrs at hand at the moment, but try to construct a new date by using 01.<current month + 1>. <Current year>  this is the first day of the next month after your finished_date. Now you can simply call date add with -1 on this new date which should result in the last day of the previous month.

Comment: The-First-Tiger plz can u write complet expression for finish_date ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may look like:

```
=DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(DatePart("yyyy", finish_date), DatePart("m", DateAdd("m", 1, finish_date)), 1))
```

For every day in a given month it calculates the last day of the given month. So for 03/30/2014 you would get 03/31/2014.

Calculation works like: Build new date which is set to the first day of the following month of a given date. Substract 1 day. Which is the last day of the month before. As we added 1 month it is the last day of the month of the given date.

---

**Edit**

Code with finished_date = TODAY + 4 Month (finished_date + 1 so it is TODAY + 5)

```
=DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("m", 5, TODAY())), DatePart("m", DateAdd("m", 5, TODAY())), 1))
```

Comment: in your expression "finish_date" is creating confusion, because i think that you want to put finish_date hard code but i want change it dynamically.. if i am wrong plz tell me what i should writ in finish_date means Fields!finish_date or other thing plz tell me and thanx for your reply.

Comment: Finish_Date is not meant to be hard coded. It is whatever field you like. It is the date from which you want to get the last day in the month of that date.

Comment: But there is not any Field, there is just TWO parameters first get current date =TODAY() and second parameter should be next 4 months (with last day of month) from first current date parameter...

Comment: So relaplace finished_date with DateAdd("m", 4, Today())